# How to check if the maximum number has more than 1

Tags: c#, arrays, max

if I have int [] number = {1,1,2,2,3,4}, I want to find the numbers that appear the most, but in this case the numbers that appear the most are 2( 1 and 2), if this happens then I want to make a sign if in this array the maximum number of numbers that appear is > 1, code :

```
        int count = 1, tempCount;
        int frequentNumber = number[0];
        int tempNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (number.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            tempNumber = number[i];
            tempCount = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number.Length ; j++)
            {
                if (tempNumber == number[j])
                {
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }
            if (tempCount > count)
            {
                frequentNumber = tempNumber;
                count = tempCount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean "i want to know if the numbers in an array are unique"?

Comment: Why do you loop in a loop? It will be easier to just loop through the array once. Are you allowed to use dictionary and Linq?

Comment: @CaiusJard no, I want to print the most number of occurrences, but if there are two or more numbers that have the highest number of occurrences I am confused about how to let me know that there are two or more numbers that have the highest number of occurrences in the array.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done idiomatically with *LINQ*.

```
int[] number = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};

var result = number
   .GroupBy(x => x) // group your numbers
   .Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count()}) // project 
   .GroupBy(x => x.Count) // group the count
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key) // order by count
   .FirstOrDefault(); // pick the highest group

foreach (var item in result)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
{ Key = 1, Count = 2 }
{ Key = 2, Count = 2 }
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MxN3T2)

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order.

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
> element is found.

[Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
> read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
> define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is
> not available at the source code level. The type of each property is
> inferred by the compiler.

[Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

> Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is the name for a set of technologies
> based on the integration of query capabilities directly into the C#
> language. Traditionally, queries against data are expressed as simple
> strings without type checking at compile time or IntelliSense support.
> Furthermore, you have to learn a different query language for each
> type of data source: SQL databases, XML documents, various Web
> services, and so on. With LINQ, a query is a first-class language
> construct, just like classes, methods, events. You write queries
> against strongly typed collections of objects by using language
> keywords and familiar operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many repeats of a number there are:

```
numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Max(g => g.Count())
```

If you want to know how many repeats and what number is repeated:

```
var e = numbers.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First();
e.Key //the number
e.Count() //the repetition count
```

If you just want to know if an array is full of unique numbers:

```
numbers.Length == numbers.Distinct().Count()
```

If you can't/may not use LINQ:

```
int max = 0;
int what = -1;
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var x in numbers){
  if(!d.ContainsKey(x))
    d[x] = 0;
  d[x]++;
  if(d[x] > max){
    max = d[x];
    what = x;
  }
}
```

If two numbers are tied for highest, these techniques only list one of them. To print both, we can adjust the last code to not track a single `what` but instead do a:

```
foreach(var kvp in d)
  if(kvp.Value == max)
    Console.Write($"{kvp.Key} occurs {max} times");
```

Similarly for the earlier techniques using LINQ groupby; can enumerate the grouping `Where(g => g.Count() == max)` but it's easiest to capture max separately, probably by doing the grouping into a variable and then doing the where max as another operation:

```
var group = numbers.GroupBy(x => x);
var maxCount = group.Max(g = g.Count());
var maxNums = group.Where(g => g.Count() == maxCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 1, tempCount;
bool isMultiple=false; //the sign
int frequentNumber = number[0];
int tempNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < (number.Length - 1); i++)
{
      tempNumber = number[i];
      tempCount = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < number.Length ; j++)
      {
          if (tempNumber == number[j])
          {
             tempCount++;
          }
       }
       if(tempCount == count)
       {
           isMultiple = true;
       }
       else if (tempCount > count)
       {
           frequentNumber = tempNumber;
           count = tempCount;
           isMultiple = false;


                
       }

       
}
```

edit:
This code for each loop, checks if tempCount equals to count and then set sign true. And if in the next loops it occurs new one, and it tempCount was more, the sign resets to false.

Comment: Although your code may work and you took some time to answer the question, it's a good idea to explain what's going on and why your question is the appropriate answer.